# AWS gets empty SSM parameter list from LocalStack

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-ssm, localstack, aws-sdk-net

I have some SSM parameters stored in LocalStack, but when the application runs is unable of getting the parameters, although the parameters are there.

The app log even says: `[AWSSDK] Found AWS credentials for the profile local`

The parameters are there as can be seen below.

Any idea why this would happen?

```
$ aws ssm get-parameters-by-path --path "/app-local/dynamodb" --endpoint-url http://127.0.0.1:4566 --profile local --recursive
{
    "Parameters": [
        {
            "Name": "/app-local/dynamodb/urls/expire",
            "Type": "String",
            "Value": "1.00:00:00",
            "Version": 1,
            "LastModifiedDate": 1656607246.131,
            "ARN": "arn:aws:ssm:us-west-2:000000000000:parameter/app-local/dynamodb/urls/expire",
            "DataType": "text"
        }
    ]
}
```

Program.cs

```
config.AddSystemsManager("/app-local");
```

appsettings.json

```
{
  "AWS": {
    "Profile": "local",
    "ServiceURL": "http://127.0.0.1:4566",
    "UseHttp": "true"
  }
}
```

Setting this code in my Main.cs:

```
var awsFile = new SharedCredentialsFile();
                if (awsFile.TryGetProfile(awsOptions.Profile, out var profile))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Found credentials for '{awsOptions.Profile}' in credentials file '{awsFile.FilePath}'.");
                }
```

It prints:

```
Found credentials for 'local' in credentials file '/root/.aws/credentials'.
```

```
root@8bb9c17a7179:/app# cat /root/.aws/credentials
[local]
aws_access_key_id = local
aws_secret_access_key = local
region=us-west-2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AWS SDK for some reason is not using the configured region, and it is trying to figure out the region from the endpoint url, which is dumb. As it cannot figure it out, when signing the HTTP requests uses the default `us-east-1` as region, causing the described problem, because Localstack has different data stores per region.

Using `http://us-west-2.localhost:4566` as service url instead of `http://127.0.0.1:4566` fixed the problem. Of course you need to add that entry in your `/etc/hosts`.

It is not a bug. It is a dumb design decision.

Comment: Check my answer below, it fixes the issue without having to change the host file.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `http://localhost:4566` if you specify the `AuthenticationRegion` property (part of [IClientConfig](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/index.html?page=Runtime/TIClientConfig.html&tocid=Amazon_Runtime_IClientConfig))

If you see the error
`Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service`, you will also have to set `BasicAWSCredentials` (as described on this [LocalStack's GitHub issue](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/1918))

**Code Snippet**

```cs
var config = new AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementConfig() 
                 {                 
                   ServiceURL = "http://localhost:4566", 
                   AuthenticationRegion = "ap-southeast-2" 
                 };
var credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("local", "local");
var parameterStoreClient = new AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient(credentials, config);
var request = new GetParametersByPathRequest()
{
   Path = "/params",
   Recursive = true,
   WithDecryption = false
};
var results = parameterStoreClient.GetParametersByPath(request);
```